# Is there a way to have pycharm always install some modules?

Tags: pycharm

For reinforcement learning, my code typically starts with these lines

```
import gym
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pylab as plt
```

Yet every new project says that these modules are not available. I have to install them via `File > Settings > Project Interpreter > +`

Is there a way to set up PyCharm so that they are installed for all projects and I can just `import` them as needed?

It turns out that the three modules are listed in `External Libraries > Python 3.5 > Lib > site_packages`. Yet I still can't import them into a new project even though they are listed in `site_packages` in *that project*. Why not?

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can tick the **inherit global site packages** option when creating a new project. Then you'll be able to import all the libraries you need to the pycharm virtual environment, provided they have been installed in your computer.

[image]